# add and remove particular value from Javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I want to filter my data from a big JSON array, for filtering we are using different parameters like Gender, Company etc.
This is filter array which will be passing to filter data.

```
filteredArray={gender:[],company:[],job_title:[],location:[],department:[]};
```

and this is function which is being called when I check or un-check some checkbox in filters.

```
  onSelectFilter(event, type,  value){
    console.log(event.checked, type, value);
    if(event.checked){
      if(this.filteredArray.gender == type){
        this.filteredArray.gender.push(value);
      }
      //if condition same for location. company etc
    }else if(event.checked){
      if(this.filteredArray.gender == type){
        var index = this.filteredArray.gender.indexOf(value);
        if (index !== -1) this.filteredArray.gender.splice(index, 1);
      }
      //if condition same for location. company etc
    }
  }
```

Here: `event.checked` will be true/false ,`type` is gender, company etc and `value` is "male" or "abc" etc.
when I un-check depend upon `type`, particular `value` will be removed.

after check or un-check this will desired output:

```
filteredArray={gender:["male"],company:["x","y"],job_title:[],location:["abc","88u","lki"],department:[]};
```

That function onSelectFilter() is not good, is there any good way to do so.
Thanks for your help.

this is output json after selecting check box of gender as "Male" and rest other parameters like company, department etc are not selected in check box

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Hardy",
        "last_name": "Shakelade",
        "email": "hshakelade0@reuters.com",
        "gender": "Male",
        "avatar": "http://dummyimage.com/194x108.jpg/dddddd/000000",
        "location": "Çepan",
        "company": "Jabberstorm",
        "job_title": "VP Product Management",
        "department": "Marketing"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Joshua",
        "last_name": "Ketton",
        "email": "jketton1@google.it",
        "gender": "Male",
        "avatar": "http://dummyimage.com/181x224.jpg/ff4444/ffffff",
        "location": "Chemin Grenier",
        "company": "Trupe",
        "job_title": "Staff Scientist",
        "department": "Research and Development"
    }........]
```

Comment: @StepUp, i have edited my question, output json has gender as "Male" and rest other parameters like company, department etc are not selected in check box.

Comment: The block for `}else if(event.checked){` is never called because it's checking for the same condition that the previous `if(event.checked){ ... }` already evaluated.

Comment: @StepUp, output array is mentioned in question. if i don't select gender then all other data with gender "Female" would come in output array as well.

Comment: @Christian, yes i forgot to add `else if(!event.checked)` in code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues that I picked up in your implementation from reading it the first time.

1. Your `if` conditions seem to be incorrect, you are trying to check `this.filteredArray.gender == type` but `type` is a string and `filteredArray.gender` is an array so those will never be equal. I think what you wanted to check here was `if (type === "gender")`
2. The condition in the `else if` part is the same as the original `if` condition. Both of them are checking if `event.checked` is truthy. I assume you meant to check that `event.checked === false` in the `else if` condition?

Based on what I understood from the question, I came up with the following implementation which is only slightly modified from yours:

```
const onSelectFilter = (event, type, value) => {
  if(event.checked){
    if (type === "gender"){
      this.filteredArray.gender.push(value);
    }

    if (type === "company") {
      this.filteredArray.company.push(value);
    }

    if (type === "job_title") {
      this.filteredArray.job_title.push(value);
    }

    //...
  } else if (event.checked === false) {
    if(type === "gender"){
      const index = this.filteredArray.gender.indexOf(value);
      if (index !== -1) {
        this.filteredArray.gender.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }

    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, it will help to reduce complexity in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` and `reduce` method:

```
const onSelectFilter = (arr, type, value) => {
  let filtered =  arr.filter(f=> f[type] == value);
  return filtered.reduce((a, c) => {
    a[type] = a[type] || { gender: [], company: [], job_title: [], 
        location: [], department: []};
    a[type].gender.push(c.gender);
    a[type].company.push(c.company);
    a[type].job_title.push(c.job_title);
    a[type].location.push(c.location);
    a[type].department.push(c.department);
    return a;
  }, {})
}
```

An example:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Hardy",
    "last_name": "Shakelade",
    "email": "hshakelade0@reuters.com",
    "gender": "Male",
    "avatar": "http://dummyimage.com/194x108.jpg/dddddd/000000",
    "location": "Çepan",
    "company": "Jabberstorm",
    "job_title": "VP Product Management",
    "department": "Marketing"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Joshua",
    "last_name": "Ketton",
    "email": "jketton1@google.it",
    "gender": "Male",
    "avatar": "http://dummyimage.com/181x224.jpg/ff4444/ffffff",
    "location": "Chemin Grenier",
    "company": "Trupe",
    "job_title": "Staff Scientist",
    "department": "Research and Development"
  }
]

const onSelectFilter = (arr, type, value) => {
  let filtered =  arr.filter(f=> f[type] == value);
  return filtered.reduce((a, c) => {
    a[type] = a[type] || { gender: [], company: [], job_title: [], 
        location: [], department: []};
    a[type].gender.push(c.gender);
    a[type].company.push(c.company);
    a[type].job_title.push(c.job_title);
    a[type].location.push(c.location);
    a[type].department.push(c.department);
    return a;
  }, {})
}

console.log(onSelectFilter(arr, 'gender', 'Male'));
```